# Use of $.getJSON() in cocoonjs

Tags: jquery, phaser-framework, cocoonjs

I have a HTML5 game working perfectly in desktop and for the leadersboards (and for more stuff) I use ajax to send parameters and receive data.

The fact is that everything is working fine but in cocoon, in cocoonjs is not working at all and I don´t know why, jQuery is supported and in theory everything should be fine. Does anyone know why is not working this code?

Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: this.baseURL+'/getScores.php',
 data: { 
      'theGame': '1', 
      'theOrder': 'ASC'
 },
 fail: function(msg){
      alert(msg);
 }
 });
```

And I´m also trying this code (not working in cocoonjs)

```
$.getJSON( STK.root.urlBase+"/getScores.php",
 { theGame: "1", theOrder: "ASC" }
)
 .done(function(data) {
      //DO STUFF
 })
 .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
     console.log( "Request failed: " + err );
 });
```

Comment: Your code looks all-right (both variants, except for the difference with the slash in the URL). What error do you see?

Comment: Tomalak, the code is ok (I edited that), it´s just simply that I was trying an absolut URL and I edited that incorrectly :) Both parts of code are working perfectly in desktop, the thing is in cocoonjs, the fail() callback is executing everytime...

Comment: With what error? Do a `console.log(arguments)` and inspect the result.

Comment: I´m getting just and "error" with this code:

`.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
     var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
     alert( "textStatus: " + textStatus );
     alert( "error: " + error );
});`

textStatus is "error" and error is nothing :)

Comment: Of course the error is something. What does the network tab of your Browser's dev tools say?

Comment: I can´t see it, I¨m in Cocoon JS Launcher and I don´t have that info, that´s the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well, everything was a CORS thing, I fixed it with this header in the php files that receive/send data:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```